# Is It Possible To See Inside the Function filter2D() in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm interested to find out how I can see the code behind the filter2D() c++ function in opencv.

I know it works, but I want to know *how*. Is there a way to view this? I've had a look in imgproc.hpp and highgui.hpp but there doesn't seem to be a filter2D() definition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the implementation of filter2D() in OpenCV source directory,

`opencv/modules/imgproc/src/filter.cpp`

or See here in [OpenCV github](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/filter.cpp) Ln->3229 if I am right.